# Does ObjCMongoDB support SSL connection?

Tags: objective-c, mongodb, ssl, connection, objcmongodb

I have to create an iOS client using MongoDB and I need to secure the connection. I'm considering ObjCMongoDB library to do it because the interface is in Objective-C. 
Can we use the ?ssl=true option in the MongoDB URI as described [there](https://api.mongodb.org/c/current/advanced-connections.html#ssl)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, nope, not at this time. The Legacy C Driver has no SSL support, and as far as I'm aware there are not yet any Objective-C bindings for the new C driver.